# How to get absolute PATH from Uri picked from Downloads folder?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore, storage-access-framework, saf

I want to get absolute path by Uri, when picking some files from Downloads folder. API level 21+.
Currently I have such errors:

```
Input Uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1603
Path: content://downloads/public_downloads/1603
Giving error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/1603
```

or this one:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:64020: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:64020"
```

depending on how I access such files. How can I do that properly? Maby you can provide some usuful link to documentation. Thanks.

This is my current solution:

```
    private FileUtils() {
    }

    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";

    public static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

    public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";

    public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        return url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://");
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // DocumentProvider
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider  ----- This if-else is working wrong.
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.parseLong(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(path) && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Intent createGetContentIntent(String mimeType) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType(mimeType);
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        return intent;
    }
} 

And this is in myActivity:
  





    public void checkPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        IMAGE_PICKER_PERMISSION_KEY);
            } else {
                startImagePickerActivity();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_PERMISSION_KEY && grantResults.length == 2
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startImagePickerActivity();
            }
        }
    
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE) {
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        //user choose 2+ images
                        int i = 0;
                        while (i < clipData.getItemCount()) {
                            onPhotoAdded(clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                            i++;
                        }
                    } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                        //user choose only 1 image
                        onPhotoAdded(data.getData());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    public void onPhotoAdded(Uri uri) {
            try {
                File f = FileUtils.getFile(this, uri);
                if (f == null) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "File is null");
                } else {
                    listOfUri.add(uri);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("LOG", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```